# Rendering a string with PHP tags into a string

Tags: php, compilation, eval

I have a string containing HTML but which also includes PHP tags (`<?php .. ?>`). I'd like to let the compiler render this into pure HTML as if it were simply in a PHP file.

I know that I can do this with files by doing the following:

```
ob_start();
include 'my_file.php';
return ob_get_clean();
```

What I really want to do is something like the following:

```
$html = '<strong>1 + 1</strong> = <?php echo (1+1); ?>';
ob_start();
echo $html;
return ob_get_clean(); // should return '<strong>1 + 1</strong> = 2'
```

Asides from parsing the string and performing evals or saving the string temporarily as file; is there any way to do this in PHP when the string has been dynamically generated? Assume that I do not have privileged access so I cannot modify my php.ini.

Comment: there must be a better way to start with, rather than this approach,. what's the source of the string?

Comment: I'm styling an XML file into HTML using XSLT. I can style the PHP tags in both, but the XSLT transformation itself produces some PHP code so I need to recompile the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = '<strong>1 + 1</strong> = <?php echo (1+1); ?>';
eval("?> $html <?php");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

> "eval — Evaluate a string as PHP code"

Comment: No, sorry, this doesn't compile since eval requires the input to not contain php tags.

Comment: It does work... however there is one bit missing... you have to close PHP tags before... `echo eval('?>' . $html);` that's because it automatically expects to be evaling PHP... but all PHP files start expecting HTML. By automatically closing PHP first, you break back in to the HTML parser mode... which will then allow you to break back in to PHP mode when your $html var starts with '<?php' - if that makes sense?

Comment: @pebbl, it does make sense, in fact I found this out shortly after posting. However, saying that this does work is like stating that I can afford a new BMW with only $5 in the bank as long as I actually have $30000 in the bank. You should really submit a new answer.

Comment: @Godwin Heh, Ah ok, I had thought it best to submit an edit to the guys answer instead... he pretty much had it right, just missed off one bit so didn't feel right duplicating. However, you are correct - it only takes a semicolon in the wrong place for code to be broken... OptimusCrime should have tested it ;) Glad you found the answer you needed anyway.

Comment: @Gowin : Ah, I missed that part. I've edited the answer now so others that might read this can find a solution to their problems.

Comment: @OptimusCrime, you also don't need the output buffering to solve this, that was just an example because it's required for `include`. You can simply return `eval("?> $html <?php");`.

Comment: @Gowin : I know that, but I included it based on your first post. I've edited the question to be as simple as possible. Might be a good idea :)